# Apply a binomial function to every row in a pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, list, testing, repeat

I am using the following code on that dataframe:
[Here picture of the dataframe used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTEQd.png)

```
not_rescued = df["not_rescued"]
rescued = df["rescued"]
breed = df["breed"]

def get_attribute(breed, attribute):
    if breed in df.breed.unique():
        if attribute in df.columns:
            return df[df["breed"] == breed][attribute]
        else:
             raise NameError('Attribute {} does not exist.'.format(attribute))
    else:
        raise NameError('Breed {} does not exist.'.format(breed))
  

def get_not_rescued(breed):
    return get_attribute(breed, 'not_rescued')
  
def get_rescued(breed):
    return get_attribute(breed, 'rescued')

def get_total(breed):
    return get_attribute(breed, 'total')

from scipy.stats import binom_test
binomial_test = binom_test(get_rescued(breed), get_total(breed), 0.08)
print(binomial_test)
```

I would like to apply the binomial function without having to call the function each time for each dog.. How could I use a list without having the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [18], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 from scipy.stats import binom_test
----> 2 binomial_test = binom_test(get_rescued(breed), get_total(breed), 0.08)
      3 print(binomial_test)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/stats/morestats.py:2667, in binom_test(x, n, p, alternative)
   2665     n = np.int_(n)
   2666 else:
-> 2667     raise ValueError("Incorrect length for x.")
   2669 if (p > 1.0) or (p < 0.0):
   2670     raise ValueError("p must be in range [0,1]")

ValueError: Incorrect length for x.
```

Comment: I find a solution. But I should avoid using a loop in Python, right ? Is there a better solution that I could use: ''' from scipy.stats import binom_test
for i in range(8):
    print(binom_test(rescued[i],100,0.08))'''

Comment: Try looking at [Apply function to every row in a Pandas Dataframe](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/apply-function-to-every-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe/amp/).

Comment: Thank ! I reached to use an  apply function.

Comment: df_test = df["rescued"]
pvalue = df_test.apply(lambda rescued_test : round(binom_test(rescued_test,100,0.08,alternative="two-sided"),4))
pvalue


pvalue_test = pvalue.to_string(index=False)
#pvalue_test
print(pvalue_test)